# Spring cloud stream: Sending two payloads?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to spring cloud stream and I am wondering if there is some way to send two payloads of a message to be processed by other services.

My use case is I have a user service which I am using as a client side application for now. I have an accounts service associated with a user and a product service.

When a user purchases a product, I am trying to send the userId, along with the productId to the account service, where the account service would send the balance and the product Id to the product service, where the product service would determine if the balance is high enough to purchase the product. Is this possible or should I try a different approach?

Here is my call from client side but only sending the user id:

```
    @GetMapping("/{userId}/purchase")
    public void buyProduct(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @RequestParam("productId") int productId) {
            Message<Integer> msg =MessageBuilder.withPayload(userId).build();
            this.purchaseProduct.send(msg);
    }
```

I was thinking using spring integration, something on the lines of:

```
@Bean
    IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(AccountChannels c) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(c.purchaseProduct())
                .handle(Integer.class,(payload,headers)->{
                    ///Handle here

                    return null;
                }).get();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions.

- Instead of sending just the `userid` as payload, send an object that contains the userid and productId
- Use a 'POST' request instead since this is a non-idempotent state changing operation.

  class PurchaseRequest{
    int userId;
    int productId;
  }

  @PostMapping("/purchases")
  public void buyProduct(@RequestBody PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest){
    ...
  }
- Consider publishing a purchase request event, the product service listens for the event and asks the account service to verify the balance.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you help me understand a little better the last point you made?